# Laravel Query Builder - how to format the query using joins

Tags: php, laravel, join, laravel-query-builder

I know this is a poorly written query. How can I re-write this using the Laravel Query builder?

```
SELECT tgi.rate, tgi.tax_types_id, tt.name, tt.sales_chart_master_id, tt.purchase_chart_master_id  
FROM tax_group_items tgi, tax_types tt 
WHERE tgi.tax_groups_id = (SELECT tax_groups_id FROM customers WHERE id=2) 
AND tt.id = tgi.tax_types_id 
AND tt.id NOT IN (SELECT tax_types_id FROM item_tax_type_exemptions WHERE item_tax_types_id = (SELECT item_tax_types_id FROM products WHERE id = 1))
```

Comment: post your eloquent models too

Comment: Please publish the model class as well.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be more easier and clearer to you if you post your relationships in the model class. If you dont know how to define relations, go to query builder section of official doc.
If you don't want to define relations or don't want to use them then use this

```
$query = DB::select('your query');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table(DB::raw('tax_group_items tgi, tax_types tt'))
    ->select(['tgi.rate', 'tgi.tax_types_id', 'tt.name', 'tt.sales_chart_master_id', 'tt.purchase_chart_master_id'])
    ->whereRaw('tgi.tax_groups_id = (SELECT tax_groups_id FROM customers WHERE id=2)')
    ->where('tt.id', 'tgi.tax_types_id')
    ->whereRaw('tt.id NOT IN (SELECT tax_types_id FROM item_tax_type_exemptions WHERE item_tax_types_id = (SELECT item_tax_types_id FROM products WHERE id = 1))')
    ->get();
```